# Is snowflake join case insensitive

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to join two tables but seems like the join is not considering case. Is the join in snowflake case insensitive?

Following query is being joined case insensitively

```
with cte_1 as 
(select  VIN,YEAR,MAKENAME,MODELNAME from TBL_A),

cte_2 as 
(select YEAR,MAKE_CHROME,MODEL_CHROME from TBL_B)

select * from 
cte_1 a 
inner join cte_2 b on 
    a.YEAR=b.year and 
    a.MAKENAME=b.MAKE_CHROME and 
    a.MODELNAME=b.MODEL_CHROME;
```

[image]

Comment: When I try this it returns no records. Have you set a non-standard collation on the DB/schema/tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per NickW comment, by default strings have no matching, thus:

```
with cte_1(YEAR, MAKENAME, MODELNAME) as (
    select * from values
        (2022, 'FORD', 'BRONCO')
), cte_2(YEAR, MAKE_CHROME, MODEL_CHROME) as (
    select * from values
        (2022, 'Ford', 'Bronco')
)
select * 
from cte_1 as a  
join cte_2 b 
    on a.YEAR=b.year 
        and a.MAKENAME = b.MAKE_CHROME 
        and a.MODELNAME = b.MODEL_CHROME;
```

gives no results:

[image]

So if we change the data type with [COLLATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation#collation-function) it will now "match"

```
with cte_1(YEAR, MAKENAME, MODELNAME) as (
    select 
        column1
        ,COLLATE(column2, 'en-ci')
        ,COLLATE(column3, 'en-ci')
    from values
        (2022, 'FORD', 'BRONCO')
), cte_2(YEAR, MAKE_CHROME, MODEL_CHROME) as (
    select
        column1
        ,COLLATE(column2, 'en-ci')
        ,COLLATE(column3, 'en-ci')
    from values
        (2022, 'Ford', 'Bronco')
)
select * 
from cte_1 as a  
join cte_2 b 
    on a.YEAR=b.year 
        and a.MAKENAME=b.MAKE_CHROME 
        and a.MODELNAME=b.MODEL_CHROME;
```

gives:

[image]

This implies that when your table was created it had collation for the column set

```
create table TBL_A(
    YEAR number, 
    MAKENAME text COLLATE 'en-ci',
    MODELNAME text COLLATE 'en-ci');

insert into tbl_a values (2022, 'FORD', 'BRONCO');

with cte_1 as (
    select * from TBL_A
), cte_2(YEAR, MAKE_CHROME, MODEL_CHROME) as (
    select
        column1
        ,COLLATE(column2, 'en-ci')
        ,COLLATE(column3, 'en-ci')
    from values
        (2022, 'Ford', 'Bronco')
)
select * 
from cte_1 as a  
join cte_2 b 
    on a.YEAR=b.year 
        and a.MAKENAME=b.MAKE_CHROME 
        and a.MODELNAME=b.MODEL_CHROME;
```

so to find that out we can look at the [COLUMNS view](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema/columns) in the information schema:

```
select 
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type,
    collation_catalog,
    collation_name,
    collation_schema
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = 'TBL_A';
```

[image]

Comment: Yes the collation_name is marked as 'en_us-ci' . Thanks!